# Incrementally Increase OST Cache Size

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, cache

We're currently undergoing a migration, and I'm trying to figure out how to steadily increase the OST cache size on our client machines. 
I've tried adding the registry key

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Cached Mode\SyncWindowsSetting
```

but that appears to affect only the cache on the first login.

Is there a way to alter the Outlook cache size after the user has set up Outlook on their machine?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What is wrong with letting the OST file grow in size as the mailbox is synchronized? Please see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445) for why I'm asking this.

Comment: So you're using Outlook 2013? Guessing so by the Registry key you've used having 15.0 in the value. What **DWORD** value are you setting for the SyncWindowSetting?

Comment: Twisty Impersonator, we're migrating our entire company from Win 7 to Win 10, this consists of around 5000 users, some of which have mailbox sizes over 50GB. It's simply not feasible for us to have every single end user download there OST files all at the same time, so I'm trying to find a way to have them cache their data on a schedule that steadily increases their cache size.

Comment: angelofdev, I'm setting up a scheduled task that increases the value weekly, 1, 3, 6, 9, and 12. The problem is just that once the profile has been created on the machine the registry key doesn't change the cache settings in outlook.

Comment: How about you instead only enable caching for smaller groups of people at a time? This could be handled via GP and AD Security Groups rather easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the registry key that effects Outlook 2013 OST caching is 
HKEY_USERS\USERSID\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\USERNAME\VariableValue\00036649
So the following script will check the current value and then change it.

```
$USERNAME = Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME –Class 
Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Username
$USER = $USERNAME.Username -replace 'domain\\'
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("$USER")
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

$SID = $strSID.Value
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -name HKU -root HKEY_USERS
$CONTENT = Get-ChildItem -path 
"HKU:\$SID\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\$user" -recurse | 
where { $_.property -match '00036649' } | select-object "Name"
$REGKEY = $CONTENT.name

if ((Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"$REGKEY")."00036649" -eq "1")
{
    reg add $REGKEY /v 00036649 /T REG_BINARY /D "03000000" /f
}
elseif ((Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"$REGKEY")."00036649" -eq "3") {
    reg add $REGKEY /v 00036649 /T REG_BINARY /D "06000000" /f
}
elseif ((Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"$REGKEY")."00036649" -eq "6")
{
    reg add $REGKEY /v 00036649 /T REG_BINARY /D "0c000000" /f
}
```